# How to best combine Regex groups and streams to search a file

Tags: regex, scala, stream

I would like to scan through a file, finding only the **first instance** of a regular expression and then return the values of the groups matched by the expression.

All my attemps so far seem very unwieldy and involve a repeated use of the regular expression, once to find the target string and then again to get the groups. I also don't like the use of the .* at the beginning and end of the Regexp.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant way of doing this.

```
  val DateRegexp = """.*(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*""".r
  val lineWithDate = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filenameGC).getLines().find{_.matches(""".*(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*""")  }
  lineWithDate match {
    case Some(result) =>
       result match {
        case DateRegexp(year, month, day) =>
          println(year, month, day)
       }
    case None =>
      println("No date found in file")
  }
```

After great input from Cyrille Corpet I now have...

```
val DateRegexp = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r.unanchored
scala.io.Source.fromFile(filenameGC).getLines().collectFirst{
                   case DateRegexp(y, m, d) => println(y, m, d)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex` already is a pattern (in the sense of pattern matching), so you can use it directly in your `case` statement:

```
fileString match {
  case DateRegexp(year, month, day) => println(year, month, day)
}
```

However, in your case, the `.*` being greedy, it will catch the last occurrence of the pattern in your string.

Thankfully, you may remove the `.*` at start and at end of your pattern, if you specify it to be `unanchored` (meaning it does not try to match the pattern to your whole string). Without the greedy `*`, you now catch the first occurence:

```
val regex = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r.unanchored

"1987-05-18 2002-12-14" match {
  case regex(y, m, d) => (y.toInt, m.toInt, d.toInt) // (1987, 5, 18)
}
```

EDIT: I realized I have not addressed the first issue of the question, which is that you do not have a `String` but a `Seq[String]`. However, once you have the extractor for a line, you only have to use it on all lines up to the first relevant one with `collectFirst`, which finds the first occurrence that matches one of the given `case`s and do something with it:

```
(lines: List[String]).collectFirst{
  case regex(y, m, d) => println(y, m, d)
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't know about `unanchored` before starting to answer your question, so I was happy to discover this.